# How kill website on IE9 or lower

Tags: internet-explorer

I want to kill my website on IE9 or lower resulting in a nice message to upgrade to a newer version or to get either Chrome or FireFox. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html), you can execute code for certain versions of IE only. The following would redirect IE9 and lower to a page on your site with an error message, for example.

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script>window.location.replace('http://example.com/no-ie.html');
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: You are a hero! Thanks!